# How To Setting Google Form Description Format with HTML Styles via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Since Google supports format settings when creating Google Forms, descriptions of questions in Google Forms can be set in bold, italics, or add hyperlinks.

With Apps Script, I can create a Form, Title, Description, or Question. But to change the Title, Description, or Question format to bold, italic, break or hyperlink format with Apps Script, I still have difficulty.

This is my Script :

```
   function editForm() {
   var formURL   = sheetRespon.getFormUrl();
   var form      = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
       
   form.setTitle("FORMULIR JURNAL PKL SMK INDONESIA")
   var description = "This is sample <b>deskripsi</b> formulir with  <i>italic text</i> and  <b><i>Bold and italic text</i></b>";  
   form.setDescription(description);
   }
```

Is it possible to use HTML code directly in Apps Script when editing forms?

Comment: I think that unfortunately, your goal cannot be achieved in the current specification. It seems that this has already been reported to the Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240108930) So, in the current specification, when Unicode is used, the text style can be changed with Unicode as a current workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64805933 But, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: The Unicode solution by @Tanaike is an excellent fit. For example, this is a way to represent the variable for your description: `convertedDescription = "This is sample "+conv.bold("deskripsi")+" formulir with "+conv.italic("italic text")+" and "+conv.boldItalic("Bold and italic text")`. The output is **exactly** as one would wish.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, how to mark my Question was solved with your solution ? I don't find  how to mark it as closed/ solved post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, I think that I will flag your question as a duplicate question. And, if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816071) was useful for your situation, you can upvote my answer.